Selecting Distinct and Total count in single SQL statement
This is how my data looks in the table. FYI. actual table contains millions of records a day.



Carrier
Numbers Sent Message
Date




Airtel
1234567890
9/5/2024


Airtel
1234567890
9/5/2024


Airtel
1234567891
9/5/2024


Airtel
1234567891
9/5/2024


Airtel
1234567891
9/5/2024


Tata
1234567892
9/5/2024


Tata
1234567892
9/5/2024


Jio
1234567893
9/5/2024


Jio
1234567893
9/5/2024


Jio
1234567894
9/5/2024



I'm trying to find a SQL statment that will provide the following output.



Carrier
Unique Number
# of Messages




Airtel
2
5


Tata
1
2


Jio
2
3




What did you try so far?

It is a count function you need; once with distinct number, once without it. Put all columns (such as carrier; possibly date, if you want to count rows per date as well) that aren't aggregated into the group by clause.
Sample data:
SQL> with temp (carrier, num_sent_msg) as
  2    (select 'Airtel', 90 from dual union all
  3     select 'Airtel', 90 from dual union all
  4     select 'Airtel', 91 from dual union all
  5     select 'Airtel', 91 from dual union all
  6     select 'Airtel', 91 from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 'Tata'  , 92 from dual union all
  9     select 'Tata'  , 92 from dual
 10    )

Query begins here:
 11  select carrier,
 12    count(distinct num_sent_msg) unique_number,
 13    count(*) number_of_messages
 14  from temp
 15  group by carrier;

CARRIE UNIQUE_NUMBER NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES
------ ------------- ------------------
Airtel             2                  5
Tata               1                  2

SQL>


Why don't you write count(num_sent_msg), but use *?

@Jonas, because there's no difference in this case. All rows contain value in NUM_SENT_MSG column, there are no NULLs. At least, I wouldn't expect any.

I know there's no difference, that's why I asked. I always prefer using column names over *, but well, it's likely just kind of taste here.

You can use this idea below query try it will solve your problem
SELECT 
    Carrier,
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Numbers Sent Message]) AS UniqueNumber,
    COUNT([Date or other related column]) AS SentMessage,
    Date
FROM 
    YourTableName
GROUP BY 
    Carrier, Date
ORDER BY 
    Carrier, Date;

COUNT(DISTINCT [Numbers Sent Message]): This counts the unique phone numbers for each carrier.
COUNT([Date or other related column]): This counts the total number of messages sent by each carrier.
GROUP BY Carrier, Date: Groups the results by CarrierandDate` so that for each day, you will see the carrier's unique numbers and the total messages sent.
Replace YourTableName with the actual name of your table.

Be sure that the dates are stored truncated in the table, if not you should group by trunc(dat) and on a table with million of records, you will probably need to add a function index.
